# I cannot get my countdown to work in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I followed a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uVXbb1ymVs) on creating a countdown timer. But I keep getting an error in the following code:

```
import time

while True:
    uin = input(">>")
    try:
        when_to_stop = abs(int(uin))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        print("not a number mate")

    while when_to_stop > 0:
        m, s = divmod(when_to_stop, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        time_left = str(h).zfill(2) + ":" + str(m).zfill(2) + ":" + str(s).zfill(2)
        print (time_left + "\r", end="")
        time.sleep(1)
        when_to_stop -= 1
print()
```

I get an error that `my editor (pycharm) doesn't recognise (end="")`

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are writing python 3 code while running python 2.

Comment: thanks, i suspected that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`end=""` was added in python 3. If it is causing error then maybe your are running a python version under python 3. (ex python 2.x)

Just replace:-

```
print (time_left + "\r", end="")
```

By:-

```
print (time_left + "\r")
```

Comment: I took out the "\r" too and it works now, it just doesn't overwrite itself but I can live with that.